# how to use my system packages as mirror to a fresh ubuntu installation

Tags: apt, package-management

Is there any way to create a repo with my current system packages and use it as repo for a fresh system installation? 
In other words what I need is to install a system wich is completely offline and therefore use the sources from a laptop which is currently updated. I might not need all the packages from the laptop, but I'm sure I won't be needing other packages.
Is there a way?

Answer (score 1):

WARNING! If Laptop A doesn't have the same CPU as the target, this might not work (might omit some CPU-specific packages).

You can get a list of installed packages with

```
dpkg --get-selections
```

You can download the binary package to the current directory with

```
apt-get download
```

I suggest you do something like

```
dpkg --get-selections >MyPackages.txt
```

Then, use the editor-of-your-choice to check to see if the selections make sense.

In a portable, high-capacity directory (e.g. the big USB key or disk you're going to take away),

```
awk '{print $1}' <MyPackages.txt |\
xargs --max-args=1 --no-run-if-empty apt-get download
```

to download all the packages listed in `MyPackages.txt`.

Read `man dpkg;man apt-get;man awk;man xargs`

Comment: I'll try your suggestion and tomorrow I'll tell you... and in fact, the hardware in both systems is 100% different.

Comment: `sudo lshw -short` on each system might help.

Comment: yes, I know how to get the hardware specs, but I'm telling that both systems are different